How do you prove that nonsingular matrices have a nonzero determinant
I was going through the following video, which was an absolutely amazing introduction to the properties of determinants, the Leibniz formula and the Cofactor expansion. The video lays out the properties of Area and Volume functions created by vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively. The following rules, which have great geometric intuition behind them, are laid out:
$$V(i,j,k) = 1$$
$$V(\vec{v},\vec{v},\vec{w}) = 0$$
$$V(c\vec{v},\vec{w},\vec{u}) = c\cdot V(\vec{v},\vec{w},\vec{u})$$
$$V(\vec{v}+\vec{v}\,',\vec{w},\vec{u}) = V(\vec{v},\vec{w},\vec{u})+V(\vec{v}\,',\vec{w},\vec{u})$$
$$V(\vec{v},\vec{w},\vec{u}) = -V(\vec{w},\vec{v},\vec{u})$$
Then, he derives the Leibniz equation and Cofactor expansion for this function. The determinant is simply a function that extends the properties of volume to higher dimensions, and so, the Leibniz formula and Cofactor expansion hold for any n$\times$n matrix. For upto 3 dimensions, this intuition is great. Thinking of the determinant as volume (or area) helps emphasize that if the determinant is zero, a dimension (or dimensions) has collapsed, which, by the rank-nullity theorem, would imply that the matrix is not full rank, is singular and isn't invertible.
However, how would you go about making this approach rigorous for higher dimensions. Firstly, you need to show that a function that satisfies the properties given always exists for any particular matrix. Then, how exactly would you show that if a function with these properties is zero, the matrix is singular/non-invertible? Typically in textbooks, they use the row approach in defining the properties of the determinant. This allows for great use with Gauss's method but is not as intuitive as the column method given above. So, with the column approach taken in defining the properties of the determinant, how can you show that a matrix with nonzero determinant is nonsingular?
Is the following reasoning rigorous enough? I suspect that all I'd need to show is that det exists for all matrices for this to be valid:
Suppose A is invertible. Then:
$$det(AA^{-1}) = det(I) = 1\implies det(A) = \frac{1}{det(A^{-1})}\neq 0$$
How would I show the reverse implies: if the determinant is non zero the matrix is invertible?

Use Cramer's rule.

Formatting note:  \det

The properties you've listed are enough to do row reduction. What happens when you have two rows that are equal?

They're both part of the equivalent statements in the Invertible Matrix Theorem.

If $A$ is singular, then $\text{im}(A)$ is a linear subspace of $ \mathbb{R}^n$ and there is a nontrivial subspace $L$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n=L\oplus\text{im}(A).$
Let $\rho:\mathbb{R}^n\to\text{im}(A)\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n $ be the identity on $\text{im}(A)$ and satisfy $\rho(L)=\{0\}$.
Now $\rho A=A$, hence $\det(A)=\det(\rho A)=\det(\rho)\det(A)$.
The whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$ inherits a basis from $L$ and $\text{im}(A)$, and in this basis $\rho$ can be diagonalised. It's eigenvalues are $1$ and $0$, so it has determinant $0$. Thus $\det(A)=0$.
This means all singular matrices have $0$ determinant.
So if $A$ has non-zero determinant, it must be invertible.
